# Weird flickering on Ionic app, running on iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios9, iphone-5

I've created an app for Android and iOS using Phonegap and Ionic Framework, the goes perfectly on Android but it has an issue on iOS specially with the iPhone 5 and the iPad (It works well on iPhone 6 and 4).

When you tap a button that makes the rol of a backbutton, the back animation is shown but inmediatly the goes back to the section where the backbutton was taped. It only happens on one section, the backbutton works perfectly on the others sections.

The HTML element is the following:

```
<a class="button button-icon button-positive button-positive icon ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="atras()">
```

The function called is "atras" which is the following (Located in the controller of the template):

```
 $scope.atras = function() {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
 };
```

Have any idea of how could i resolve this? Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: The version iOS is 9.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, there is a notable patch for Ionic UIWebView that are built on iOS9. Without this patch, you will experience such flickering issue when you tap on some back buttons in navigation bar. Please apply ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch for your project then it's all done.

https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/

Comment: Most likely answer with ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch solutions.

Comment: the issue is still there with my app even after adding the patch.Can anyone let me know what can be done

Comment: Hey @AliSadiq, is this the issue you never experienced in older versions of iOS?

Comment: It'd be great if you can attach links to screenshots or videos for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately iOS 9 has some bugs with with `window.location` that impact the  `router-ui` and also some empty href links `<a href="#">` like yours.

Take a look to these articles from Ionic's blog:

- [Preparing for iOS 9](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/)
- [iOS 9 Potential Breaking Change](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/)

There you can find the link to the [iOS9 patch for angular](https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c) and this for [Disable App Transport Security in iOS 9](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa)

Answer (score 1):

Add these two properties to prevent flickering effects:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Apply also to flickering elements which AREN'T being animated for the same fix.

Comment: I don't know if it's the same case at all but I had weird, app-breaking flickering and adding this style rule fixed it:

    * {
      backface-visibility: hidden !important;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    }

Thanks to you!